# Eclipse shortcuts do not work ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I have installed Eclipse Neon with C++ features on Ubuntu 16.04.

My problem is that some more unusual shortcuts do not work such as "copy lines" (ctrl+alt+down), or "move lines up" (alt+up), or autocomplete (ctrl+space) for example.
The others more usual like "ctrl+c" or "ctrl+f" or "ctrl+z" do work.

I have tried to restart eclipse, and even the computer. I have restored the defaults key bindings but they do not work anymore. I think they worked just few times at the beginning after installing eclipse.

I don't want to uninstall and then reinstall eclipse because it is not a good solution if I have to do that every time, it will be just bothering at will. While searching for solutions on Google, it seems it is a quite recurrent issue for eclipse, but there is never real answers for them.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may have a better chance at getting an answer on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Had the same problem, I guess shortcuts started working for me when I opened java project instead of a c++ one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys and change commands involving arrow keys or other keys that don't work such as:

```
ctrl+Alt+upArrow
```

To something involving a key that registers when set in binding, such as:

```
ctrl+Alt+d
```

Eclipse was having trouble with arrow keys and function keys on my system and this solved it. Hopefully helps someone who ends up on this page.

Running Arch linux version = Linux 4.15.7-1-ARCH